# how do i create character counter from contents of a TextField widget

Tags: flutter, state

Hello I'm new to flutter, I'm trying make a character counter below a textField widget. Here's my current code

```
TextField(
  maxLines: 3,
  controller: _cancellationReasonCtrl,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color:primaryColor
      )
    ),
    labelText: "type minimum 30 characters"
  ),
)
```

and here's how i displayed the number

```
Text((30 - _cancellationReasonCtrl.text.length).toString()+" character left")
```

but it doesn't update the number when i change the content of text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter will update the UI only when you will change the variable and call setState.

So you should do something like:

```
setState( () {
   Text((30 - _cancellationReasonCtrl.text.length).toString()+" character left")
}):
```

Read more about states at : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/State.html

Comment: oh, thanks for answer, where do I put this code? onChanged property?

Comment: @Necrofantaisie it will work well on device.. the lag is because of screen refresh is 60 fps... Please upvote, as well, if you like the answer. Thankyou!

Answer (score -1):

Use inputFormatters property

example:

```
TextFormField(
      inputFormatters: [
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
      ]
    )
```

namespace

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

or just used minLength: 10, property

Comment: sorry, if I'm not clear enough. I'm trying to do is creating character counter, not limiter.

Comment: yes got automatically charecter count below textfield just used min charecter filed

Comment: and if you set own text error then also properties is available set own error text,  otherwise you can mange text charecter size in OnChanged with setState function

Comment: this is `TextFormField` not `TextField` as the OP asked for